# Recursive Counting By Integers Up and Down

Tags: java, recursion

I received this assignment today and I am kinda stuck on it.

This is what the assignments say:

> Write a method called `recursiveUpAndDown()` that takes one non-negative integer parameter,  recursively starts at zero and prints all the integers from zero to the parameter (that is, prints 0, 1, 2, etc. all the way up to the parameter), then recursively starts at the integer parameter and prints all the integers from the parameter to zero (that is, prints the parameter, the parameter - 1, the parameter - 2, etc. all the way down to 0).

I was able to write the code for writing the coding to count down then up but unable to do up then down. Here is the code I wrote

```
class myCounter{

    static void recursiveDownAndUp(int i)
    {

        if (i < 1)       

        return;

        else
        {
            System.out.printf("%d ",i);
            recursiveDownAndUp(i-1); // recursive call
            System.out.printf("%d ",i);
            return;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        recursiveDownAndUp(10);
    }

}
```

We are not allowed to use 2 parameters, a helper method or a global variable. I know it seems hard, at least for me, but the professor said it is doable

Comment: "We are not allowed to use 2 parameters, a helper method or a global variable."  Q: Are you allowed to use a return value?

Comment: By non-negative, is zero included?

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes return values are fine

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Yes I believe so

Comment: So for 0, do we just print 0?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance I am going to assume, yes.

Answer (score -1):

```
static String recursiveUpAndDown(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return "";
    String x = recursiveUpAndDown(n - 1);
    System.out.print(n + " ");
    return n + " " + x;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print(recursiveUpAndDown(10));
}
```